# Use javascript in Photoshop to modify the contents of a text item

Tags: javascript, photoshop

I know how to set the contents of a textitem in Photoshop using code like this

```
var al = doc.activeLayer;
if(al.kind == LayerKind.TEXT) {
    //get the textItem
    var ti = al.textItem;
    //change contents
   ti.contents = "stackoverflow";
}
```

However is it possible to modify just part of its contents and apply formatting.  For example in the work "stackOverflow" I just want to select the first letter and make the font 30px and leave the rest unchanged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no easy way to do that to my knowledge. First of all, it's not possible with DOM, so forget using `textItem.contents`. With AM the tricky part is that AM code for text layers is really precise. Every time you change something, it defines all possible parameters for all "blocks" of text, for example in this case I had a 35px height text layer written in Gudea font and I changed one letter to 70px: https://pastebin.com/XLP64azz
You may see that there's a lot of garbage in there and the text layer is considered as 3 separate blocks now: letters from 0 to 5 (lines 64-65: `stack`), from 5 to 6 (lines 217-218: `O`) and from 6 to 14 (lines 281-282: `verflow`). A little bit lower to each block there are lines that set the size, for example

```
desc62.putUnitDouble( cTID('Sz  '), cTID('#Pxl'), 35.000000 );
desc62.putUnitDouble( sTID('impliedFontSize'), cTID('#Pxl'), 35.000000 );
```

I know it's possible to remove most of the excessive descriptors (like if you remove descriptors that define font name, the layer will have the font name it had originally), so I guess it's possible to shrink this huge function to several lines that only change a size of a particular letter, but I didn't try that. I guess the algorithm will be like this:

1. get font size and text with DOM;
2. split text to blocks (like `from 0 to 1 + from 1 to last character` to change a font size of a first letter);
3. use this function to set parameters to specific blocks;

And there'll be problems if there're several styles already exist in the text layer: you'll have to parse layer contents with AM, get all the styles of all the blocks to find the one you're referring to...

Comment: Hi - I was actually looking for DOM script to do this but you've made it clear its not possible.  I will play with the code you have provided at least its a start.

Comment: I am a web developer and just started photoshop scripting.  This AM code - I know you can get access to it via the ScriptListener plugin but can you actually program in it i.e. is there some documentation on what this stuff is and how to use it?

Comment: Yes, the provided code is from Scriptlistener and was a bit beautified by xbytor's script for AM code. You can program it, it's just difficult to read. There're libraries to convert AM code input and output to more readable JSON structures (ActionManagerHumanizer) but I didn't come across any comprehensive documentation apart from Davide Barranca's recent book on professional photoshop scripting