# Photoshop Scripting: How to change a certain part of text in a text layer

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-script

I'm trying to have text in my document but get the last two characters of the text contents to change size.

For example, I have a text layer in a group and I set the contents to "100ft". I would like to make the last two characters "ft" a different size than the rest of the text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use javascript in Photoshop to modify the contents of a text item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54684487/use-javascript-in-photoshop-to-modify-the-contents-of-a-text-item)

Answer (score 0):

it's very easy!
1 choose your text layer
2 choose type tool from left side tools
click on your text with type tool selected
select letters that you want to change them sizes
from top panel choose any size you need
[image]