# How to change font size of layer's single character using Photoshop Script?

Tags: fonts, size, photoshop

I have a text layer "text" with 30 font size (like all characters in string), i need to change single character font size, there wil be something like that: t(size 30) e(size 40) x(size 50) t(size 60).
But i can change only size of all text layer using artlayer.size.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O68wN.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use javascript in Photoshop to modify the contents of a text item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54684487/use-javascript-in-photoshop-to-modify-the-contents-of-a-text-item)

Answer (score -1):

You can select a single character (T) after that open character panel, then select font size, whatever you want.

Then again select the next character (E) after that same open character panel, then select a font size.

Comment: And where is the SCRIPTING in this instruction?